# All equal values created by Faker using Factory Boy

Tags: django, faker, factory-boy

Using Factory Boy and Faker in a Django project, I notice that objects created using Factory Boy, and using Faker to create names (company names in this example) doesn't create a unique name for new objects.

**Main question:** are we using Faker wrong when using it as a separate library (first example), or is there just something inherent about Factory Boy that prevents Faker from working correctly as a separate library, when used with Factory Boy?

```
import factory
...

from faker import Faker
from faker.providers import company
...

fake = Faker('nl_NL')
fake.add_provider(company)


class PolicyBrandFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PolicyBrand

    name = fake.company()
```

Results in (Pycharm debugger screenshot):
[image]
(the point being non-unique company names)

In the Factory Boy documentation I read that they have a wrapper around Faker, and using that I do get unique results:

```
import factory
...


class PolicyBrandFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PolicyBrand

    name = factory.Faker('company', locale='nl_NL')
```

And the result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Django forms and setting a default date, the `name` value is set at the time the class is first defined.

You need to use [`LazyAttribute`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#lazyattribute)

```
name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.company())
```

Comment: Oh man, that I didn't realize that myself. Back to school again I guess, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The supported way to use Faker in factory_boy is through the [`factory.Faker`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#faker) helper:

```py
class PolicyBrandFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PolicyBrand

    name = factory.Faker('company', locale='nl_NL')
```

This will also connect Faker's random seed management to factory_boy's random seed.

If you want to go without the helper, you must use one of the lazy helpers:

```py
fake = Faker('nl_NL')

class PolicyBrandFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PolicyBrand

    name = factory.LazyFunction(fake.company)
    name_alt = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: fake.company())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class variable. `name` is defined when the class is defined, to the result of a single invocation of `fake.company()`

```
class PolicyBrandFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PolicyBrand

    name = fake.company()
```

If  this was a straightforward Django model I'd expect to have to override `__init__`, but I haven't any knowledge of `factory.django.DjangoModelFactory` and what metaclassing magic it might be performing.